# Special characters from Database to CSV thru batch job

Tags: oracle, batch-file, csv, special-characters

I have tried going thru any questions related to my problem in this site. I only found a reverse of my problem :(

I am trying to run a **batch file** which inturn call a **.sql** to fetch data from **Oracle DB** and put it into a **CSV**.
**In this process, any non-English(or Special characters) are being converted into '?' symbols.**

Can you help in getting the data as it is into the CSV.

Comment: what version of Oracle, what operating system, what is your language set to in Oracle, what language is the operating system set to....

Comment: Show your batch file.

Comment: `chcp 65001` to change pagecode to unicode. Then run batch. What is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Maker sure that your data base character set is utf8 (AL32UTF8)